# Opening and closing elements in LPEG for Pandoc Reader

Tags: lua, grammar, pandoc, peg, lpeg

I am working on a simple Pandoc reader that can process some of the basic html-like syntax used in forums (such as `[b]bold[/b]` and `[h1]Header[/h1]`).

I managed to get a basic reader working with LPEG (as described in the pandoc documentation), but the solution I landed on feels clunky. Is there better way to define the grammar around start and end tags (using things like priorities or negative lookahead, or LPEG groupings)?

Here was what I was able to get working:

```lua
local P, S, R, Cf, Cc, Ct, V, Cs, Cg, Cb, B, C, Cmt =
  lpeg.P, lpeg.S, lpeg.R, lpeg.Cf, lpeg.Cc, lpeg.Ct, lpeg.V,
  lpeg.Cs, lpeg.Cg, lpeg.Cb, lpeg.B, lpeg.C, lpeg.Cmt

local whitespacechar = S(" \t\r\n")
local wordchar = (1 - whitespacechar)
local spacechar = S(" \t")
local newline = P"\r"^-1 * P"\n"
local blanklines = newline * (spacechar^0 * newline)^1
local endline = newline - blanklines
local emph_start = P"[i]"
local emph_end = P"[/i]"
local strong_start = P"[b]"
local strong_end = P"[/b]"
local header_start = P"[h" * (R"17" / tonumber) * "]" 
local header_end = P"[/h" * R"17" * "]"
local tag_start = emph_start + strong_start + header_start
local tag_end = emph_end + strong_end + header_end

-- Grammar
G = P{ "Pandoc",
  Pandoc = Ct(V"Block"^0) / pandoc.Pandoc;
  Block = blanklines^0 * (V"Header" + V"Para") ;
  Para = Ct(V"Inline"^1) / pandoc.Para;
  Inline = V"Emph" + V"Strong" + V"Str" + V"Space" + V"SoftBreak" ;
  Str = (1 - (whitespacechar + tag_end + tag_start))^1 / pandoc.Str;
  Space = spacechar^1 / pandoc.Space;
  SoftBreak = endline / pandoc.SoftBreak;
  Emph = emph_start * Ct(V"Inline"^1) * emph_end / pandoc.Emph;
  Strong = strong_start * Ct(V"Inline"^1) * strong_end / pandoc.Strong;
  Header = header_start * Ct(V"Inline"^1) * header_end / pandoc.Header;
}

function Reader(input)
  return lpeg.match(G, input)
end
```

And here's the kind of text I'd like to transfrom:

```
[h1]A Test[/h1]
The [i]quick[/i] dog jumped over the lazy stream!
Tags should be able to be applied [b]mid[/b]word.
```

Comment: I don't feel so much clumsy for the way you define the start and end rules. I personally use LPeg.re to define grammars, which has a cleaner writing style.

Comment: @AlexanderMisel - I'm glad to hear it doesn't look too bad. When I looked at the re module, it didn't seem to offer non-greedy matches (which, in my mind, would make this so much simpler since I could define things as (tag) (non-greedy match) (close tag). Is there something else in lpeg.re that would simply this that I overlooked? You mention it's cleaner?

Comment: Non-greedy matching of course can be written in PEG, where `S <- E2 / E1 S` matches E1 non-greedily followed by E2. I'll recommend you read [my blog on LPeg](https://medium.com/@AlexanderMisel/lpeg-and-peg-practices-b3d0fc00457e) and PEG related papers to know more about PEG.

Comment: @AlexanderMisel Thank you for the link - I actually used your blog while writing my initial grammar. 

Could you provide an example of a non-greedy match that doesn't capture the terminator (open tag)(non greedy match)(close tag)? What you're describing still captures E2 as part of S (it's the difference of 'up to and including' vs 'up to'), which still creates a problem here since what I want to get is everything between the tags, rather than everything including the closing tag.

Comment: When you don't want to consume tokens, you can use **and-predicate** (which is commonly called a **positive lookahead**). In the case of non-greedy match, you can write `S <- &E2 / E1 S`.

Comment: @AlexanderMisel - thanks. I tried that, but I seem to be having issues. Taking the Emph rule as an example, I added a new rule `NotTag = #tag_end + P"1" * V"NotTag"` and switched the Emph rule to `Emph = emph_start * Ct(V"NotTag"^1) * emph_end`, but that resulted in the error 'Empty Loop in rule "Emph"'. I was able to get the rule to run by removing the `^1` over V"NotTag" in the Emph rule, but that that doesn't seem to provide what I'm looking for when looking at the debug output (it doesn't read the full word). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Could you please provide the test case and your expected output?

Comment: This is such a wonderful question, but unfortunately not a good fit for stackoverflow. https://codereview.stackexchange.com is probably the better site for this.

Comment: @tarleb - got it. I'll post a new, more focused question specifically on the LPEG look ahead problem discussed here in the comments.